# How to extract url from get_the_term_list?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

How do you extract the url from :

```
$url = get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'nom-origin')
```

I have tried many things but i just don't get it. The only solution i got was this but i know it's just too messy :

```
$url = get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'nom-origin');//,'<h3>Job Category:</h3> ', ', ', '' );
$url_tmp1 = explode("href=\"",$url);
$url_tmp2 = explode("\" rel=\"tag\">",$url_tmp1[1]);
$url_simple = $url_tmp2[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

[`get_term_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link) gives you the link of a particular taxonomy term.

```
$terms = get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'nom-origin' );
$urls = array();
foreach( $terms as $term )
{
    $url[] = get_term_link( $term->slug, 'nom-origin' );
    //Or do whatever you want here with the url
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Never try to parse complete markup when you don't have to. Follow the function calls.

1. [`get_the_term_list` uses `get_the_terms`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/category-template.php#L1092)
2. [`get_the_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) returns an array of terms
3. You can use that array plus [`get_term_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link) to get your URLs

And [the code for that is in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link).

```
$terms = get_terms('species');
echo '<ul>';
  foreach ($terms as $term) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug,species').'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
  }
echo '</ul>';
```

You may want to build an array instead, but its the same idea:

```
$terms = get_terms('species');
$turls = array();
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $turl[] = get_term_link($term->slug,'species');
}
```

Comment: Thanks s_ha_dum. This is definitely going in the good direction for me. And what if i want to link this to a thumbnail instaed of an name ? I have try $term->thumbnail but it doesn't work.